# Updating javascript inside a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-table

I am trying to write a script that will update an `HTML` table. I have been able to get the `tr` and `td` to update.

The `th` though is proving to be harder.

I am currently calling the  through:

```
<div class ="container" >
<div class ="row">
     <div class ="col s12">
     <table id="noteTable" class="note-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <? for(var i=0;i<levelTitle.length;i++){ ?>
          <th><?=levelTitle[i];?></th>
  <?}?>
          
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="notes-body">
     
    </tbody>
  </table>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I need to refresh the following on command though:

```
<? for(var i=0;i<levelTitle.length;i++){ ?>
          <th><?=levelTitle[i];?></th>
```

any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you are doing to update the `tr` and `td` elements?

Comment: I’ll post it in the morning but I am running an array in a seperate script that is calling td and tr from a google script which is where the th is also stored

Comment: What you did is backend and you have to use frontend (normal) javascript to update the DOM elements.

Comment: @idfurw how do I do that?

Comment: The same as `td`. Please show the code you update `td`.